# error deploying in heroku, rejected error

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

help me plis !!!  I cant deploy mi mean stack app to heroku

mi git repository with the code:

https://github.com/blinkking349/meanstack

log of error:

```
-----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > meanapp@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_9dad4ae1_
       > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
       
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "~4.0.2,": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.3rpWs/_logs/2020-10-18T02_45_15_324Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! meanapp@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meanapp@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.3rpWs/_logs/2020-10-18T02_45_15_340Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

```
Invalid tag name "~4.0.2,"
```

It looks like you [have included a comma inside your version string for TypeScript in your client directory](https://github.com/blinkking349/meanstack/blob/fd1ce7b9d1de11dd31c3430b2cf60158497adfdb/client/package.json#L34):

```
"typescript": "~4.0.2,"
```

Get rid of it:

```
"typescript": "~4.0.2"
```

Then commit and redeploy.